# Three.js - TubeGeometry Inside a CubeGeometry Issue

Tags: three.js, bounding-box

Using Three.js, I have plotted a TubeGeometry and the points used for the plotting, ranges between -8000 to +8000 (The points used for plotting is obtained from a XML file and it may change dynamically). I have tried to draw a CubeGeometry enclosing the TubeGeometry using bounding box approach.
When I zoom in/zoom out or rotate the Cube, I want the TubeGeometry to shrink and fit inside the Cube. But it does not happen.
Please help me resolve this issue.

//points to plot the TubeGeometry are dynamic and are read from a file

```
extrudePath = new THREE.SplineCurve3(points); 
extrudePath.dynamic = true;
var segments = points.length;

tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(extrudePath, segments, 60, radiusSegments, closed, debug);
tube.dynamic = true;

THREE.GeometryUtils.explode(tube);

tube.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
tube.dynamic = true;

tube.computeBoundingBox();
var centerX = 0.5 * ( tube.boundingBox.max.x - tube.boundingBox.min.x ); 
var centerY = 0.5 * ( tube.boundingBox.max.y - tube.boundingBox.min.y ); 
var centerZ = 0.5 * ( tube.boundingBox.max.z - tube.boundingBox.min.z ); 

var boundingBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( centerX, centerY, centerZ );        

var boundingBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, transparent: true, opacity: 0.7 } );
boundingBoxMesh = new THREE.Mesh( boundingBoxGeometry, boundingBoxMaterial);
scene.add( boundingBoxMesh );
```

Comment: Show us the code that you tried.Read this stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add the code u have tried.